# Android VM heap size

Tags: java, android, memory

I can't understand what is android app heap size. 
Is it overall maxumum memory I can allocate both from java and frome native code? If yes then why on my google nexus S. this code

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));
```

dysplays 50331648 = 48MB 
but dumpsys meminfo displays 
 Native       13       16       12    84028    83457       18

and I can easily allocate say 74MB

```
int size = 1024*1024*74;
char* s = new char[size];
```

Comment: The VM heap size doesn't apply to native allocations.

Answer (score 5):

Well, heap size is actually a programming concept, much more than it's an Android one. You can read about it [here](http://www.azulsystems.com/technology/java-heap-size), but it's really (short story) how much memory the VM is using and it's allocated independently from your app.

The memory allocated to your app is allocated dynamically. So, if you ask your app to allocate more memory you will see it grow. But it can't grow indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Heap size is that amount of RAM that can be allocated. Each app is on a tiny Dalvik Virtual Machine. Each VM will have some heap space allocated.

And, there is a pre-defined heap-size settings inside `/system/build.prop` file for each device.